# add subviews to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have trouble when I add subviews to UITableViewCell.
It's working when the table size is below the iPhone size.

But when the size is bigger, it makes some horrible effect like this when I'm scrolling :

[image]

It's supposed to be like this :

[image]
Then I think it comes from the cell reuse.
Here is a sample of my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //construct the cell
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                       reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease]; 


        //clear the previuous content
        NSLog(@"Il y a %d subviews", [[[cell contentView] subviews] count]);
        //[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        NSLog(@"Il y a %d subviews", [[[cell contentView] subviews] count]);
        [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
    }    

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell addSubview:titleEvent];
            break;
        case 1:
            //load the owner logo
            [cell addSubview:logoAsso];
            break;
        case 2:
            //StartDate
            [cell addSubview:clockImage];
            break;
        case 3:
            //EndDate
            [cell addSubview:clockEndImage]; 
            break;
        case 4:
            //Address
            [cell addSubview:adress];
            break;
        case 5:
            //map
            [cell addSubview:map];
            break;
        case 6:
            //header
            [Graphism configureSeparationCell:cell];
            break;
        case 7:
            //descritpion
            [cell addSubview:descriptionEvent];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The subviews are attributs of the class, and configured in the method viewDidLoad.
If you can tell me what i'm doing wrong, that would be such a relief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:


        if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:11]) {

            titleEvent.tag = 11;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:titleEvent];
        }


        break;
    case 1:
        if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:11]) {

            logoAsso.tag = 11;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:logoAsso];
        }
```

like this do for all switch cases

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"] autorelease];

    } else {
        UIView *subView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        if ([subView superview]) {
             [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    subView.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:subView];
    [subView release];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[cell.contentView addSubview:clockImage];