# UITableViewCell showing double embedded UITextfields

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with regular UITableViewCell, but I don't use any of UITableViewCell's lables. I just use the cell to embed a label and a UITextField to input some data. Problem is when you scroll up or scroll down and the UITableviewCell redraws itself, it draws an overlapping UITextFieldView over the old one and you see doubles! I'm thinking that maybe since I do put these UITextFields into a dictionary, it might save the textfield with a strong pointer, and try to make another one and just overlap. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *orderpoint = [self.orderpoints objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = @""; //black out text

CGFloat calculatedHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *productLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.bounds.size.width - 50.0, calculatedHeight)];

productLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@. %@",
                       [orderpoint objectForKey:@"sequence_nr"], [product objectForKey:@"name"]];
//word wrapping
productLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
productLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //infinite number of lines
productLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];

[cell.contentView addSubview:productLabel];

 //create the cell's textfield
UITextField *cellTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width - 50, cell.bounds.size.height - 30, 50, calculatedHeight - 20)];
cellTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cellTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; // will only need to end a count
cellTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; // TODO make it go to the next items key, or make it exit out
cellTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cellTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; //align to the right
//cellTextField.delegate = self; //will need to set delegate, maybe
cellTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
cellTextField.enabled = YES;
cellTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; //add bezel rounded look to textfield
cellTextField.delegate = self;

[cell.contentView addSubview: cellTextField]; //add the textfield to the cell
// save to dictionary, using a dictionary because not certain if this is created in order to use an Array
[self.textFieldDict setObject:cellTextField forKey:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: check my answer in the following thread! it may help you

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535637/reusablecellwithidentifier-issue-in-cellforrowatindexpath/10535788#10535788

Comment: Yes, your answer has definitely helped me in thinking, now I've got another problem, though. I have some UITextFields that I need to record their values and if the cell comes back after they scrolled, then the value should return to the text field.

Comment: have you checked if the values in the texfield stays in there even after scrolling or not

Comment: I solved it by storing it in an immutable dictionary using an NSNumber as they key and the UITextField's text as the value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this as a reference: [add subviews to UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173432/add-subviews-to-uitableviewcell)

I just first checked to see if this view was added from before, and if it was, then don't add it again. It has nothing to do with the cell being nil. Unless I missed something? all I know is that this seems to be working fine, now.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *orderpoint = [self.orderpoints objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = @""; //black out text

CGFloat calculatedHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *productLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.bounds.size.width - 50.0, calculatedHeight)];

productLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@. %@",
                       [orderpoint objectForKey:@"sequence_nr"], [product objectForKey:@"name"]];
//word wrapping
productLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
productLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //infinite number of lines
productLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];

[cell.contentView addSubview:productLabel];

if (![cell viewWithTag:1])
{
    //create the cell's textfield
    UITextField *cellTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width - 50, cell.bounds.size.height - 30, 50, calculatedHeight - 20)];
    cellTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cellTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; // will only need to end a count
    cellTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; // TODO make it go to the next items key, or make it exit out
    cellTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cellTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; //align to the right
    cellTextField.delegate = self; //will need to set delegate, maybe
    cellTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    cellTextField.enabled = YES;
    cellTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; //add bezel rounded look to textfield
    cellTextField.delegate = self;

    cellTextField.tag = 1; //set tag to 1

    [cell.contentView addSubview: cellTextField]; //add the textfield to the cell
    // save to dictionary, using a dictionary because not certain if this is created in order to use an Array
    [self.textFieldDict setObject:cellTextField forKey:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
}

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your cell.Try this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//It will check whether cell in there or not, then deque the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

    NSDictionary *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *orderpoint = [self.orderpoints objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = @""; //black out text

    CGFloat calculatedHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *productLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.bounds.size.width - 50.0, calculatedHeight)];

    productLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@. %@",
                           [orderpoint objectForKey:@"sequence_nr"], [product objectForKey:@"name"]];
    //word wrapping
    productLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    productLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //infinite number of lines
    productLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:productLabel];

     //create the cell's textfield
    UITextField *cellTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width - 50, cell.bounds.size.height - 30, 50, calculatedHeight - 20)];
    cellTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cellTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; // will only need to end a count
    cellTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; // TODO make it go to the next items key, or make it exit out
    cellTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cellTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; //align to the right
    //cellTextField.delegate = self; //will need to set delegate, maybe
    cellTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    cellTextField.enabled = YES;
    cellTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; //add bezel rounded look to textfield
    cellTextField.delegate = self;

    [cell.contentView addSubview: cellTextField]; //add the textfield to the cell

    return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either don't use reusability and always alloc the cell at each time or

make a check after dequeue (like this)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil)
{
  // make text field and label an add tag
}

//and outside this by using tag fetch the labels and textField and clear the textFields.
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I just found out and made my answer about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the condition like this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         }
```

Comment: That doesn't matter cause my cell doesn't have this built with the cell identifier. I add these in by hand, programatically. I just found the solution, BTW.